# 302 Redirect for Google AJAX Page

Tags: python, ajax, urllib2

I am attempting to grab data off a Google Reseller Panel for which there is no API.

I am able to log in successfully with urllib2 and cookiejar, and I can see secure data, however the data I need is loaded with AJAX.

When I attempt to access the AJAX endpoint directly, I get a 302 or 404 redirect. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
import cookielib, urllib2, urllib, re, pprint


cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [
    ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 Firefox/3.6.11'),
    ]


# Define URLs (borrowed this from Google voice script on Github)
login_page_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=grandcentral'
authenticate_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth?service=grandcentral'
gv_home_page_url = 'https://www.google.com/voice/#inbox'

# Load sign in page
login_page_contents = opener.open(login_page_url).read()

# Find GALX value
galx_match_obj = re.search(r'name="GALX"\s*value="([^"]+)"', login_page_contents, re.IGNORECASE)

galx_value = galx_match_obj.group(1) if galx_match_obj.group(1) is not None else ''

# Set up login credentials
login_params = urllib.urlencode({
    'Email' : "<my username>",
    'Passwd' : "<my password>",
    'continue' : 'https://www.google.com/voice/account/signin',
    'GALX': galx_value
})

# Login
opener.open(authenticate_url, login_params)

# Open GV home page
gv_home_page_contents = opener.open(gv_home_page_url).read()

# Fine _rnr_se value
key = re.search('name="_rnr_se".*?value="(.*?)"', gv_home_page_contents)

if not key:
    logged_in = False
else:
    logged_in = True
    print "Logged in!"

    reseller_home = opener.open("https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/<my reseller domain>/Reseller2Customers#Reseller2Customers")
    print reseller_home.read() #prints data behind the login, http status code 200

    opener.addheaders += [
    ('Referer', 'https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/<my reseller domain>/Reseller2Customers'),
    ]


    reseller_ajax = opener.open("https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/<my reseller domain>/Reseller/GetSubscriptions?sortField=CREATION_DATE&sortAscending=true&nextToken=&customerDomainPrefix=covision.com").read()
    #this gives me error 302 or 404
```

Comment: Any details on the redirects themselves? When do you get a 302, when do you get a 404, what are the differences? Do you get the same redirects in a browser? Did you track the headers with a HTTP debugger (the net panel in Firebug, Network panel in the Chrome developer tools, etc.)?